# Deploy BIRT Viewer 3.7.1 into Tomcat Server 7.0

Tags: tomcat, birt

I've deployed successfully BIRT Viewer 3.7.1 into a web application using Glassfish Server 3.1.2. I used the JSP taglib with a JSF 2.0 dynamic web project (v2.5).
Now I'm trying to switch from Glassfish to Tomcat 7.0 Server because I'm having many display problems with Glassfish but when I execute the web page containing the JSP taglib I get this error:

> The requested resource (/birt/frameset) is not available.

I think the problem is related to the deployment of BIRT Viewer into Tomcat. I'm getting this error in this two cases:
- I copied the war file (birt.war) into the Tomcat's Webapps folder and I deployed it from the Tomcat manager.
- I tried also to copy the WebViewerExample folder into Tomcat's Webapps folder.

For the Glassfish deployment I deployed the war file from the manager and it worked without problem.
So How can I deploy successfully BIRT viewer into a Tomcat Server???

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this tutorial](http://terrarum.net/administration/deploying-birt-on-tomcat.html#tomcat). Here you can also find how you have to run a report.

But first make sure you can open birt example throug `http://127.0.0.1:8080/birt` or `http://localhost:8080/birt`.

Or in your case maybe `http://localhost:8080/WebViewerExample`.